# Dynamically Group Table with Pig Latin

Tags: group-by, apache-pig

I have a table, and am trying to collect basic statistics on very numerous and specific groupings of the data. Here are the types of groupings that I would like to be produced in as parsimonious a statement as possible:

```
    GROUP table BY (Anchor1, Anchor2, Col1); 
    GROUP table BY (Anchor1, Anchor2, Col1, Col2); 
    GROUP table BY (Anchor1, Anchor2, Col1, Col2, Col3); 
    .
    .
    .
```

It would be desirable to have all of these groups be unique so I can use a FOREACH to calculate the statistics I need.

Comment: I think PIG is the wrong tool for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks lie you need [CUBE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#cube), pig 0.11 has such command